# Google Maps API isn't loading map

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio, intellij-idea

I've been trying to get Google Maps working for hours, but all I get is a gray screen. No map at all. I know similar questions have been asked here and I read all of them without getting any further.

A few hours ago I managed to get the Maps working when running the app from my computer, but when installing the APK, it didn't work. So I noticed that there are different API keys for debugging and the release. I decided to start all over again, with generating new keys and so on. So I removed my existing keys from Google, generated new `google_maps_api.xml` files and followed the instructions.

But now, when running the app from my phone I am getting the following error message:

```
E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: (OLD_API_KEY)
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): (MY_FINGERPRINT);(PACKAGE_NAME)
```

So, first of all, how do I ensure that "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled? On the Google API website I can only find a **Google Maps Android API** that I enabled. I can't find anything about **v2**.

And, how can I "Ensure that the following Android Key exists". I removed the `OLD_API_KEY` because I wanted to start from the beginning. No idea where it is coming from now. I obviously don't have it. So I can't ensure it is there. Why can't I just use a new one that I generated? And why does it even know my old key, that I already removed?

If I understand everything correctly, I am supposed to generate one API key for debugging and add it to my `google_maps_api.xml` in the debug folder. And for the release I generate another key and add it to the `google_maps_api.xml` in the release folder. Do I also need to add an API key to my `AndroidManifest.xml`? At the moment I have this between my `application` tags:

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

Where `@string/google_maps_key` is my debugging key.

My main problem is, why I need to ensure that an old api key exists, that I already deleted. How can I tell Android that I want to use a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! It turns out that it took a long time until the API keys are actually available to the app. A lot longer than those 5 minutes mentioned on the API page.

So, when you an API key and get the same error message as me, it is probably best to just have a small break and check again in like 20 minutes until the API key is available.